# Are Maggy the Frog and The Ghost of High Heart the same person?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

For a while now this has been niggling away at me; **are Maggy the Frog and The Ghost of High Heart the same person?**

I haven't been able to find any conclusive evidence either way, but there's a lot of signs *for* and *against* them being the same person:

**[Maggy The Frog](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maggy)**

For:

- Short / squat woman
- Very old
- Can tell prophecies
- Speaks in prophetic riddles

Against:

- Last seen in the Westerlands (by Cersei)
- Is actually Jeyne Westerling's great-grand-mother
- Originally from Essos
- Yellow eyes

**[The Ghost of High Heart](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ghost_of_High_Heart)**

For:

- Short / squat woman
- Very old
- Can tell prophecies
- Speaks in prophetic riddles

Against:

- Last seen in the Riverlands (by Arya)
- Is related to Jenny of Oldstones and the whole [Summerhall incident](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tragedy_of_Summerhall) somehow
- No signs of knowing High Valyrian (like Maggy) or being Essosi
- Red eyes

---

<sup>**Extra reading:**</sup>

- [Westeros discussion](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/90577-what-is-the-difference-between-jenny-of-oldstones-maggie-the-frog-and-the-ghost-of-high-heart/)
- [Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/2g8pqw/spoilers_all_maggy_the_frog_is_the_ghost_of_high/)

Comment: Bullets one through four are really nothing more than a common trope for the fortune telling witch from the woods?

Comment: As I recall, Maggy was the Westerosi name for "Maegi" (Essos name for mage woman), and there was also mention that she came from Essos, whereas the Ghost of High Heart was thought to be possibly of the Children of the Forest.

Comment: @TLP Random note: I feel like you haven't answered much here for a while. I know you are/were annoyed at some stuff. FWIW, you were one of the people whom I looked up to for interesting and informative answers on ASOIAF when I first started :)

Comment: @Mooz That's good to hear. Yes, the tv-show has diverged so much from the books and the type of questions have changed that I don't often feel I have anything unique to add, except in comments.

Comment: @TLP Let's take this to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39179/game-of-thrones-spoiler-chat)

Comment: @TLP There's an explicit reference in the books where someone says something like "They called her Maggy or something" and the listener responds "Maegi?" Found it: Feast for Crows, Cersei talking to Qyburn, 3rd last Cersei chapter.

Comment: I personally favor the theory that Ghost of High heart is the old women who came to court with Jenny and prophecized that Prince that was promised would be born from line of Aerys and Rhaella. Maggy the frog doesn't fit imo, she is not even Westerosi let alone descended from cotf like the Woods witch. Ah one of the higher mysteries of ASOIAF!

Comment: Also, Cersei threw some potion in Maggy's eyes and she was screaming. What potion was that? Could that have changed yellow eyes to red?

Comment: @Aegon interesting, wasn't the high heart lady also blind or nearly blind? Or did I remember that wrong?

Comment: for the record: I don't personally think they're supposed to be the same person, they're just very interchangeably similar in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes - I believe they're the same person.  The speech patterns, the prophetic ability, and the size - all are practically identical.  It's either a really odd coincidence, or they're the same person.

I wrote something more detailed regarding this, if you're interested:

https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/2g8pqw/spoilers_all_maggy_the_frog_is_the_ghost_of_high/

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Please feel free to integrate your greater detail into your answer. We are looking for detailed reasoning, not statement of opinion. Also, answers which primarily refer to a link for their information are discouraged.

Comment: Yes, this answer would be greatly improved if you could [edit] it to add a more detailed explanation, perhaps by copying from the link you provide. Thanks! :-)